# Firebase email link authentication crashing our Flutter app on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-authentication

We are using authentication by email link in our Flutter app with firebase_auth package, and we are seeing crashes on iOS devices with

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
The link provided is not valid for email/link sign-in. Please check the link by calling isSignInWithEmailLink:link: on Auth before attempting to use it for email/link sign-in.
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x18f2095f0 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18ef2bbcc objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x18f0ffb28 -[NSCache init]
3  Runner                         0x102fde5ec +[FIRAuthExceptionUtils raiseInvalidParameterExceptionWithReason:] + 30 (FIRAuthExceptionUtils.m:30)
4  Runner                         0x102fcf970 -[FIRAuth internalSignInAndRetrieveDataWithEmail:link:callback:] + 729 (FIRAuth.m:729)
5  Runner                         0x102fd0028 -[FIRAuth internalSignInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential:isReauthentication:callback:] + 770 (FIRAuth.m:770)
6  Runner                         0x102fcef5c __43-[FIRAuth signInWithEmail:link:completion:]_block_invoke + 562 (FIRAuth.m:562)
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x18eece9a8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x18eecf524 _dispatch_client_callout
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x18eeacb3c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$armv81
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x18eead54c _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$armv81
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x18eeb684c _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18ef20b74 _pthread_wqthread
13 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18ef23740 start_wqthread
```

We added some logging for investigation and saw that invalid link was

```
com.xxxx.xxxx://google/link/?request_ip_version=IP%5FV6&match_message=No%20pre%2Dinstall%20link%20matched%20for%20this%20device%2E
```

It seems that it doesn't affect 100% of users who are trying to log in with an email link and we were not able to reproduce it on our devices even once. What could produce a link like that?There doesn't seem to be any documentation that would mention this error message